# Issue when trying to map interface to class type in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

**Question Background:**

I am simply setting up a Unity container object, registering the types of the selected interface and the class that inherits it, then trying to return the implementation of it.

**The code:**

Unity:

```
namespace ABC.Tools.VersionControl
{
internal class Unity
{
    internal static ITfsVcPromotionManager CreateUnityObjects()
    {
        var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

        unityContainer.RegisterType<ITfsVcPromotionManager, TfsVcPromotionManager>();

        //****ERROR*****
        return unityContainer.Resolve<ITfsVcPromotionManager>();
    }
  }
}
```

The interface - ITfsVcPromotionManager:

```
namespace ABC.Tools.VersionControl.TfsVersionControl
{ 
    interface ITfsVcPromotionManager
    {
        void CheckoutTfsItem(IVersionControlItem tfsItem);

        int CheckinTfsItem(IVersionControlItem tfsItem);
    }
}
```

The class that inherits the above interface - TfsVcPromotionManager

```
namespace ABC.Tools.VersionControl.TfsVersionControl
{
internal class TfsVcPromotionManager:ITfsVcPromotionManager
{
    private ITfsVcQaCheckoutWorker _checkoutWorker;

    private ITfsVcQaCheckinWorker _checkInWorker;

    private VersionControlServer _tfsServer;

    private TfsVcCheckoutItem _checkoutItem = new TfsVcCheckoutItem();

    public TfsVcPromotionManager(/*IVersionControlItem tfsItem*/ ITfsVcQaCheckoutWorker checkOutWorker, ITfsVcQaCheckinWorker checkInWorker, VersionControlServer tfsServer)
    {
        if (checkOutWorker == null || tfsServer == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("tfsItem or tfsServer objects cannot be null");
        }

        _checkoutWorker = checkOutWorker;

        _checkInWorker = checkInWorker;

        _tfsServer = tfsServer;
    }

    public void CheckoutTfsItem(IVersionControlItem tfsItem)
    {
        if (tfsItem == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("TfsItem cannot be null.");
        }

        _checkoutWorker.CheckoutTfsQaItem(_tfsServer);
    }

    public int CheckinTfsItem(IVersionControlItem tfsItem)
    {
        if (tfsItem == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("tfsItem cannot be null.");
        }

        return _checkInWorker.CheckinTfsQaItem(tfsItem);
    }
}
```

**The error message:**

Result Message: 
Test method ABCTestProject.TFStests.Check_Interface_CheckOut_Method threw exception: 
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Adp.Tools.VersionControl.TfsVersionControl.ITfsVcPromotionManager", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, ABC.Tools.VersionControl.ITfsVcQaCheckoutWorker, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

**Can anyone tell me why this will not map correctly from the interface?**

Comment: Have you tried registering the constructor arguments?  It looks like Unity does not know how to build the arguments your constructor needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complaining about not being able to resolve `ITfsVcQaCheckoutWorker`.

The only unity mapping you've done is for `ITfsVcPromotionManager`. When you resolve the interface, it creates an instance of `TfsVcPromotionManager`, whose constructor accepts two more interfaces: `ITfsVcQaCheckinWorker` and `ITfsVcQaCheckoutWorker`

You haven't registered those interfaces with unity (aka type mapping), so it doesn't know how to construct a concrete class for them.

I don't know what the names of your other classes are, but you should just be able to register them immediately after the other one:

```
internal static ITfsVcPromotionManager CreateUnityObjects()
{
    var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

    unityContainer.RegisterType<ITfsVcPromotionManager, TfsVcPromotionManager>();
    unityContainer.RegisterType<ITfsVcQaCheckinWorker, TfsVcQaCheckinWorker>();
    unityContainer.RegisterType<ITfsVcQaCheckoutWorker, TfsVcQaCheckoutWorker>();

    return unityContainer.Resolve<ITfsVcPromotionManager>();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Grant. You got me on the right track with checking the ITfsVcQaCheckoutWorker object that I wasn't setting through the constructor of the promotion manager in Unity. Sorted now.